# Is InetAddress a static class? why do we not use new key word with it?

Tags: java, networking, inetaddress

Why we have not used `new`keyword in the following program?

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
public class InetDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName("www.pinterest.com");

            System.out.println("Host Name: "+ip.getHostName());
            System.out.println("IP Address: "+ip.getHostAddress());
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

Comment: `getByName` is a static method https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

> Is `InetAddress` a static class?

Well, in a sense yes.  All top-level classes are implicitly static ... in the sense that they don't require an instance of an outer class.

<sup>But you are not asking the right question.  Static classes and static methods are different concepts ...</sup>

> Why do we not use `new` key word with it?

<sup>Now ... the right question.</sup>

Because `InetAddress.getByName(...)` is a `static` method call that creates and returns an instance of `Inet4Address` or `Inet6Address` which are subtypes of `InetAddress`.

Why did they do it this way?  Why not just `new` it?

`InetAddress` objects are typically created by calling `getByName` or a related method on a `String` representing hostname or an array of bytes.  This will give you either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, or a mixture of both (with the `getAll` methods).  Since the true type of the result depends on the actual runtime arguments, it is not possible to do this with a constructor and `new`.

There is another reason as well.  In fact there is some caching going on under the covers.  If the argument to (say) `getByName` is a DNS name string, avoiding expensive DNS lookups is a good performance optimization.  So results of lookups are cached, and a `getByName` call can return an `Inet4Address` or `Inet6Address` that was created previously.  You can't do that with a constructor and `new`.

As @Turing85 notes, this is an example of the factory method design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [documentation of `InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html), we see that this class does not provide public acessible constructors. It uses the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead.